# How to decompress bzip2 data in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bzip2

I have data coming from the API in the bzip2 compressed format. How do i decompress it to string in client side (jquery/js) ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/cscott/compressjs) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If client and server are designed to handle the `application/x-bzip2` you don't have a lot of work to do. If you need to decompress raw streams you can try these libraries

```
https://github.com/antimatter15/bzip2.js
```

or

```
https://github.com/kirilloid/bzip2-js
```

If you're using npm you could look at

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bzip2
```